# Drawing from bucket: likelihood of consecutive draws.

Tags: probability

Drawing from a bucket of: 3 red balls and 10 green balls, what is the likelihood of the 3 red balls being drawn consecutively? What is the likelihood of all 3 being drawn in some sequence of 4 draws? 5 draws? .... taking all 13 draws to see all 3?

How would I create a distribution of the likelihoods from 3 (all consecutive) to 13 (as separately drawn as possible)?

Comment: For example: G, G, G, .... R, R, R would be 3 consecutive. And G, G, G ..... R, G, R, R would be a span of 4.

Comment: Are you drawing with or without replacement?  It sounds like without.  Please clarify.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes without replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ${13 \choose 3}$ orders for drawing all $13$ balls.  A run of three can start at $11$ positions, so the chance of getting the three consecutive is $\frac {11}{13 \choose 3}$  Count the number of orders that get you three within a span of four (but presumably not including the ones that have three in a row) and you will get that one.

Comment: So for span of 4: 
A run of 4 can start at 10 positions, and be done in 4 choose 3 different ways. That gives me 4*10. Subtract 10 from this (all the span 3 starting in the last 10 positions). So span 4 (w/o span 3) total would be 30?

Comment: No, there are only two patterns of three in a run of four that do not have three in a row, so only $20$

Comment: Oh right the triples get double counted per starting position in 4 choose 3.

Comment: Another way to look at it, more useful for the other parts, is that once you select the span of four, you have to have the first and last. You then have two choices for the middle one.